# Why does GCC implement std::to_string using std::vsnprintf?

Tags: c++, string, gcc, compilation, printf

Recently, I looked into GCC's `basic_string.h` and noticed that all `std::to_string` overloads are implemented using `std::vsnprintf` like for example:

```cpp
inline string
to_string(int __val)
{
    return __gnu_cxx::__to_xstring<string>(&std::vsnprintf, 4 * sizeof(int), "%d", __val);
}
```

Wouldn't this introduce a lot of overhead? Stringifying an integer base 10 is possible in just a few lines of code, so why would this be implemented using `vsnprintf`?

Comment: Inverting the question: presumably those "few lines of code" are already implemented as efficient as possible in vsnprintf, so why reimplement it?

Comment: What overhead would `std::vsnprintf` have? Since it's inline, `to_string` should be as fast as `vsnprintf`.

Comment: It would require parsing the string `"%d"` first before actually converting the int to a string. This step is completely unnecessary. Also, any variadic function has some overhead pop its arguments off the stack and from the looks of it, `std::vsnprintf` will be called via function pointer which is also not free unless inlined.

Comment: I don't see any calls to vsnprintf in the code after optimization: https://godbolt.org/z/c4YYK6 And the compiler is smart enough to replace `std::to_string(42)` with the string literal "42"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looked good enough considering they had lots of other stuff to implement for C++ 11.

They [optimized](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/cd0b94e650a880b2ab04922e476aa28007277d5c#diff-0b77da6b28cbea2f0e793090fd6cb058) it recently with gcc 10 release.